# Firestore set fails on first try but works on second

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple firestore set operation like so

```
var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('sessions').doc(this.state.userID);
docRef.set({
   Name: seshName,
   Type: theType,
}).then(()=> {
   resolve(true);
});
```

but for some reason, it always fails on the first try after app install, but then subsequent attempts are fast and smooth.

Anyone encounter similar experiences? Any clues?

Comment: How do you know it fails? Have you tried using `catch()` after `then()` to see if there is an error message?

Comment: well it just hangs and hangs....the above code never finishes and then the outer Promise just waits and has no errors

Comment: Maybe it's finishing with an error, and you don't know about it because you never used `catch()` on the promise to find out what went wrong.

Comment: The code you shared looks fine at first glance. You say: "the outer Promise just waits", but I don't see any outer promise here, so it's hard to help. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help. I found the cause. Adding .catch does not help as it just hangs as usual without any output.

It seems that Firestore only allows 1 connection at a time? This issue only happens if I do a DB action right before this .set operation, it seems that the previous DB action isn't complete yet.